# How to use VC++ copy every file from flash drive to paste in folder and format flash drive?

Tags: c, visual-c++, command-line

I want to build easy clean virus in flash drive by First, copy every file in flash drive to paste in another folder. After that, format flash drive and copy file from folder back to flash drive. I use VC++ MFC. I try to find about copy and format drive function but I'm not found the code for copy all file. So, I try to run command line in system() function but when I run

> system("format f: /Q");

It need to press enter. **I want to use VC++ format drive with out press anykey and It will very good if not show window of DOS.** please help me.

Answer (score 0):

- To copy the files, you can use ShFileOperation function.
- To format, you can use SHFormatDrive; but will also warn the user.

I don't think there is a "high level" API that will let you format a disk silently; this is for security reason, you do not want malicious people add "rotten easter eggs" in code to format the users' disk.

Good luck.

Comment: Note: `ShFileOperation` is (purposely?) broken when copying to/from an external drive with `FOF_SILENT`

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I had need of the same, and Windows does not make APIs available to easily format a disk, you must perform all the low-level operations yourself. [AutoFormat for Windows](http://neosmart.net/blog/2013/autoformat-for-windows/) is a patched command-line format utility that does not required user intervention.

Unfortunately, you cannot use `SHFileOperation` and co. to copy files to an external USB silently. If you use the `FOF_SILENT` or `FOF_NO_UI` to copy to a USB on Windows XP SP3 the operation [will silently and inexplicably fail](http://osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=214368). If you're not targeting Windows XP, then by all means, here's an example of how to use `SHFileOperation` to [copy a directory's contents recursively to an external drive](https://gist.github.com/1290539) without user intervention.

Comment: Thak for Answer. I try to use SHFormatDrive but it show UI for click OK. I download AutoFormat for Windows and extract file. it is .exe , when I double click that file it not show anything. So, I don't know how to format and how can I use low-level format drive. It have no example.

Comment: If you don't know how to use command line utilities, I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I run in cmd but It have to type Y for format like this .how to format with out type anykey or press enter with C language. C:\Users\PKRU\Downloads\AutoFormat>AutoFormat F:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

WARNING, ALL DATA ON NON-REMOVABLE DISK
DRIVE F: WILL BE LOST!
Proceed with Format (Y/N)? Y
Formatting 152617M

Comment: No, you don't. It'll show that text, but won't wait for you to press Y.